# Where to get these nodes that don't appear in the search menu?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I am a beginner and am trying to replicate node groups I see in images.

Forgive me if this is a stupid question to you, but I can't seem to find certain nodes.

For example, I see the IOR node in someone's setup,

[image]

but I can't seem to find it when I search for it.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get these "hidden" nodes?

**EDIT:** This is NOT a duplicate. The duplicate mentioned is talking about nodes in the compositor, while these are actual nodes in the material node editor.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate; the IOR is a node in material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IOR is just a regular numeric value, there is no specific node for it.

What you see in that image is just a regular node with a renamed title, the actual node type is a simple *Input > Value*.

You can change the label of any node from the sidebar. Just select a node, expand the shelf with the <kbd>N</kbd> key or from the little arrow, and change the *Label* field to your liking.

[image]